# bad file descriptor and fatal error when entering phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

Need some help. I'm new to MySQL, and whenever I enter phpmyadmin, i get this.

Notice: include(): Read of 5393 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 571

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer/../slim/psr7/src/Cookies.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 571

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Slim\Psr7\Cookies" not found in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\slim\psr7\src\Factory\ServerRequestFactory.php:99 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Http\Factory\ServerRequestFactory.php(41): Slim\Psr7\Factory\ServerRequestFactory::createFromGlobals() #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Common.php(84): PhpMyAdmin\Http\Factory\ServerRequestFactory::createFromGlobals() #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(40): PhpMyAdmin\Common::run() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\slim\psr7\src\Factory\ServerRequestFactory.php on line 99

This has been driving me nuts for quite a while now. And I'm about to pass the deadline for my school activity.

I've been looking through the internet for a solution to this, but found none.

Comment: I may sound like a Microsoft support right now, but have you tried reinstalling XAMMP?

Comment: @DiMithras yes, I've tried reinstalling XAMPP, still the same error.

Comment: Kk. Another wild guess, could you try some other software like [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/)? To see if it's the phpmyadmin problem or the XAMMP DB in general.

Comment: @DiMithras Tried it now, didn't work as well.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].